# How do I optimize this Java cube root function for BigInteger?

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, mathematics, fixed-point

I find that this function is one of the biggest causes of slow program execution. I can write a square root version with BigInteger only, but with the cube root, the algorithm sometimes gets caught in an endless loop unless I also use BigDecimal, because the values of `r` and `s` never reach equilibrium. I've already used tricks like `leftShift` to multiply by 2 and `s.multiply(s)` in place of `s.pow(2)` to make it faster, but having to use BigDecimal is still slowing it down. Any idea how I could approach this problem?

```
public static BigDecimal THREE_D=BigDecimal.valueOf(3);

public static int UP=BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP;

// other statements

public static BigInteger cbrt(BigInteger n)
{
 BigDecimal m=new BigDecimal(n);                          // BigDecimal copy
 BigInteger r=BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(n.bitLength()/3);    // initial estimate
 for(BigDecimal s=BigDecimal.ZERO;                        // different from r
     !r.equals(s.toBigInteger());                         // loop test: does r=s?
     s=new BigDecimal(r),r=new BigDecimal(r.shiftLeft(1)) // Convert to BigDecimal,
      .add(m.divide(s.multiply(s),UP))                    // do the tricky division,
      .divide(THREE_D,UP).toBigInteger());                // and convert back.
 return r;                                                // return the value
}
```

**Edit:** Followup to this question can be found [here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56719)

Comment: Can you post an input for which the BigInteger-only version does not terminate?

Comment: @mjolka The number 5.

Comment: @mjolka It hangs on 4, actually.

Comment: I think you can terminate when `r <= s`. See http://ideone.com/QH2cFe.

Comment: @mjolka I discovered that your algorithm does not work on all numbers, not even perfect cubes. Try it on 111(cubed)=1367631. I guarantee you'll get 113 as your answer.

Comment: Good catch! I wonder where I went wrong.

Comment: New attempt is [here](http://ideone.com/R84vRM). Based on the square root algorithm in [A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=hXGr-9l1DXcC&lpg=PA37&ots=yx41DMCHGc&dq=cube%20root%20algorithm%20termination&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q=cube%20root%20algorithm%20termination&f=false).

Comment: That algorithm returns a bad value for 7, and it hangs on all perfect cubes, at least the way I wrote it.

Comment: It returns the integer part of the cube root, so for 7 the answer would be 1. Did you want the closest integer instead? It doesn't hang for any value in 1 ... 400,000 -- can you provide an input for which it hangs?

Comment: I'm also confused by your implementation returning 2 for `cbrt(13)` and 3 and `cbrt(14)`. http://ideone.com/T0SjPl

Comment: @mjolka my implementation of your algorithm returned 4 for 7! Also, the BigDecimal version is _supposed_ to return rounded values.

Comment: @mjolka I have a followup [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56719).

Comment: Did you follow the links I posted? How is rounding 2.35... to 2 and 2.41... to 3 consistent?

Comment: What's important is that the values of perfect-cube cube roots are all correct. Whether or not other values are exact does not matter.

Answer (score 10):

Your current code is totally unreadable and very hard to understand.

#### For vs. While

You've literally packed everything inside a for-loop without a body. WHY!?

This would be a lot more readable using a while-loop.

```
BigDecimal s = BigDecimal.ZERO;
while (!result.equals(s.toBigInteger())) {
    s = new BigDecimal(result);

    // Convert to BigDecimal, do the tricky division,
    // and convert back.
    BigDecimal temp0 = new BigDecimal(result.shiftLeft(1));
    BigDecimal temp1 = temp0.add(valueCopy.divide(s.multiply(s), UP));
    BigDecimal temp2 = temp1.divide(THREE_D, UP);
    result = temp2.toBigInteger();
    iterations++;
}
```

The `temp0`, `temp1`, and `temp2` stuff can be written on one line, but I thought it deserved to be broken up among a few lines to be more readable.

---

#### Comments

Some unnecessary comments:

```
// other statements
// BigDecimal copy
// return the value
```

Please don't add comments about what you're doing, add comments for explaining *why* you are doing it. The code often tells us what you're doing.

Explaining what you're doing is OK for totally non-understandable parts though, these comments are helpful:

```
// Convert to BigDecimal,
// do the tricky division,
// and convert back.
```

---

#### Variable names

```
BigDecimal s;
BigInteger r;
BigDecimal m;
```

Please don't use one-letter variable names!

Explain what you're variable name is used for `r` seems to be for `result`, which is a much better variable name than `r`. I don't understand what `s` and `m` are used for exactly so I can't come up with a better name for those. Admittedly, my `tempX` names used above are also bad names, I hope you can come up with better ones.

---

#### Another approach:

Your code is already faster than anything I would be able to write by hand. I don't know if you're aware of it already or not, but there is however an in-built Java method you can use for this job - If you're willing to drop some precision for huge numbers.

I tried to compute the cubic root of `4.781260832191688e49`

One in-built method call returns `3.6295056667577016E16`.

Your code returns `36295056667577090`

So there's a difference of `74`, for a number of the order 4*10^49 I think that's pretty good.

The correct result with a lot of precision is:

```
3.6295056667577090244467986066615526182629927485862843007... × 10^16
```

So what's the secret method call then you ask?

```
Math.pow(4.781260832191688e49, 1.0 / 3.0);
```

Comment: My precision with the number I'm cube-rooting _must be exact!_

Comment: I'm testing for perfect cubes and/or sums of positive cubes.

Comment: Incidentally, my question was about optimization, not readability!

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Incidentally, it's hard to help you improve performance when the code's unreadable. Besides, one thing does not have to exclude the other.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink How big numbers do you want to know the cube-rooting of?

Comment: As big as I need to go. I'm checking very large Fibonacci numbers, and I need to check all possible combinations for each number. Eventually I want to check numbers with as many as 200 decimal digits, and accuracy is key.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I understand your problem a lot better now. I would recommend that you post a follow-up question, preferably with the variable names improved and the `for`-loop written as `while` instead. This will make it easier to help you with what you really want help with, and it will not have any impact on performance - positive or negative.

Comment: I have posted [a followup](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56719).